# Access gmail other than mine with gmail API

Tags: python, gmail-api

I have activated the Google Gmail API within my account and recieved the api key. If i want to access `other@gmail.com`, do i need to set up the app from that email? Or can i access it from my application using api keys created from the developer console within `myemail@gmail.com`?

My app is written in python if that matters. Will be running off a CentOS server

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I assume API key means you are referring to public API keys.

[API keys](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_apikeys) do not grant access to any account information, and are not used for authorization. If you want to access other users information(like gmail,calendar(which are not public) etc) then you have to go with [OAUTH 2.0](https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/#usingkeys).

When you use OAuth 2.0 for authentication, your users are authenticated after they agree to terms presented to them on a user consent screen. Here is the link for gmail [OAUTH 2.0](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server)

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: My application will visit a gmail account every day and parse certain messages in the inbox for strings. Is the API overkill? I was seeing some things about the `imaplib` and the `email` library. Do these align better with what I am after? I will have account / passwd access to the account, although its not mine so I don't really want to set up the Google developer platform and an app within their account